# Skip rendering children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Is there a way in React to skip over rendering children? I have existing DOM nodes on a page that I'd just like to wrap in a React component.

My use case is rendering the frame but not the static contents, which are pre-existing DOM nodes.

Something like:

```
const Frame = (props) => (
  <div class="frame">
    <SkipRender>{props.children}</SkipRender>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Just don't add `{props.children}`? It's really unclear what you're asking

Comment: If you want to see them on the screen they need to be rendered at least once. If you mean they are static elements on a page and you don't want to re-render them when dynamic neighbors change, then break them out into their own component.

Comment: I'd like to render around existing DOM nodes that are already on the page.

Comment: @Matt, is it possible to share skipRender component file as well

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by _"render around"_? Are you saying that you'd like to bring existing elements into your component? If so, for what purpose? You could certainly manipulate the existing DOM but I just can't fathom why

Comment: Not exactly. I have a page that has existing HTML elements on it already. I'd like to use React to provide interactivity around those existing HTML elements. Imagine markdown content with an interactive "Like" button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, when you say 'static children', you mean you don't want to rerender them? If so, then I have a solution for you.

React has a feature called memoization, which remembers a value and only updates it when the values it depends on (its 'dependencies') get updated. We can implement it through the `useMemo()` hook. A `SkipRender` component will look something like this:

```js
function SkipRender(props) {
    const children = useMemo(() => {
        return props.children;
    }, []);
    return children;
}
```

What we're doing here is taking in the passed children elements, memoizing it (remembering its initial value), and keeping it static. The empty dependency array `[]` on the 4th line means `children` variable doesn't have any values it depends on, so it will not reevaluate its value. Since we're storing React elements to it, this will make it so those elements won't rerender after the initial render, even if the passed values change. Let me know if this helps, or if you need more clarification!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually don't want to render <SkipRender> at all. Just leave the existing DOM as is. If I understand useMemo correctly, you need to still pass props.children in as React components. What I'm asking for is to leave the contents alone.